# Connect to database (ADO.NET, SQL Server)

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ado.net, entity-framework-4.1

I created an ADO.NET Entity Data Model, using [this instruction](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-%28data%29/creating-model-classes-with-the-entity-framework-cs). I have two new classes:

```
namespace Parser
{
    public partial class advert : EntityObject
    {
        ///////////
    }

    public partial class test_workEntities1 : ObjectContext
    {
       ///////
    }
}
```

Then I created the following class:

```
namespace Parser
{
    public class BdProvider
    {
        public void InsertAdv()
        {
            advert adv = new advert();
            test_workEntities1 f = new test_workEntities1();

            adv.adress = "adress 1";
            adv.const_link = "domain.com";
            adv.count_room = 10;

            f.advert.AddObject(adv);
        }
    }
}
```

And I have created the following console application:

```
namespace TestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BdProvider bd = new BdProvider();
            bd.InsertAdv();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the application, I see:

> The specified named connection is either not found in the
>   configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider,
>   or not valid

StackTrace:

> System.ArgumentException не обработано Message=Указанное именованное
>   соединение не найдено в конфигурации, не предназначалось для
>   использования с поставщиком EntityClient или недопустимо.
>   Source=System.Data.Entity StackTrace: в
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionSt
>   ring(String newConnectionString) в
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(String
>   connectionString) в
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateEntityConnection(Str ing
>   connectionString) в System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(String
>   connectionString, String defaultContainerName) в
>   Parser.test_workEntities1..ctor() в
>   C:\proj\Parser\Model1.Designer.cs:строка 34 в
>   Parser.BdProvider.InsertAdv() в C:\proj\Parser\BdProvider.cs:строка 28
>   в TestApp.Program.Main(String[] args) в
>   C:\proj\TestApp\Program.cs:строка 21 в
>   System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[]
>   args) в System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, String[] args) в
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssem bly() в
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state) в
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   ignoreSyncCtx) в
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) в
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() InnerException:

I tried to create test_workEntities1, using different connectionString, but I was not successful.

My connectionString is

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="test_workEntities1" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=PKVZALE\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test_work;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: is this project in a class library?

Comment: @levi, http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/832/problemconnection.png The class BdProvider and the class Parser are contained in a project class library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the connection string the `TestApp` configuration file.

Currently, you have it in the `app.config` file of the `Parser` project, however, as you are running the application via the `TestApp` project, .NET is looking for settings in this project.

// Expanded Answer

The `app.config` can be created in the root folder of your project.  You can do this by copy/paste from `Parser` project or by using the following instructions from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms184658%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> **To add an application configuration file to your C# project**
>
> 1. On the Project menu, click Add New Item.
>
>    The Add New Item dialog box appears.
> 2. Select the Application Configuration File template and then click Add.
>
>    A file named app.config is added to your project.

Comment: where I need to put the file? I've tried to put a file in a folder TestApp\app.config, TestApp\bin\Debug\app.config

Answer (score 1):

You need to do 3 things when you have an **entity framework - EF** in a different project:

1. Connection String in EF project
2. Reference in another project
3. **EF Connection string in another project**